# How to run background service in android

Tags: java, android

I want to fetch phone contacts and send it to server all this i have to do in background how could it be done.

I have written a service, it works fine on emulator but when i run apk on actual device application hangs up. and also service not started.

I have declare sercice in manifest as
      
call service as from fragment as

```
getActivity().startService(
                new Intent(getActivity(), DBupdateservice.class));
```

Comment: Can you put your log file and the service class?

Comment: Any log? service class code? AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: override IntentService instead of Service

Comment: @Override
 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
   List<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
// fetch contacts from phone....
   JSONObject json = null;
// send data to server
   for (int l2 = 0; l2 < personname.length; l2++) {
    json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(PHONE_BOOK_URL
      + personname[l2] + "&phone_no=" + number[l2]
      + "&email=" + emailID[l2], "POST", param);
   }
 }
  return START_STICKY;
 }

Comment: <service
            android:name="com.BNMCombines.service.DBupdateservice"
            android:enabled="true" />

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you don't have the service in your manifest, or it does not have an < intent-filter > that matches your action. You should see in your LogCat some warnings that may help.

And you should start the service like this:

```
startService(new Intent(this, UpdaterServiceManager.class));
```